# How to fix an error of execution of graphviz (and PATH)?

Tags: python, graphviz

when I try to run a python project, I have an error : "graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg', '-O', 'Digraph.gv'], 
make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH"

I tried to pip uninstall then pip install, but nothing. I'm not sure to understand what is "PATH"...

I'm using a mac (OS Catalina).

Thank you to help me !

Comment: Graphviz is an entirely separate program you need to install; `pip` has nothing to do with that, it can only install the Python module needed to talk to Graphviz.

Comment: Here is what I did : I also used 

`conda install python-graphviz`